# Count to max value in one excel cell then contintue counting in another

Tags: excel, count, spreadsheet

Not sure how to describe this, but here goes.
I have a work time sheet - where the first 40 hrs are paid at rate-X and 41+ are paid at rate-Y.
The data to count is in one column.  Example below:

```
date worked  | hrs worked
9-6-13       | 10
9-7-13       | 8
9-8-13       | 15
9-10-13      | 12 
------------------------
Total Hrs    | 45
Hrs 0-40     | **40   <formula for this?>**
Hrs 41+      | **5    <formula for this?**

Rate 0-40    | $10
Rate 41+     | $5

Total wage 0-40 hrs: $400     
Total wage 41+ hrs:  $25
```

From the example - I need to count the hrs up to for and apply the $10/hr rate.  Beyond that in a different cell continue counting and apply the $5/hr rate.  IF the hrs are less than 40 - the second rate would not apply.

Is this possible???

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2):

For the first range of 0-40 hours, you can use this:

```
=IF(B6 > 40, 40, B6)
```

Assuming that B6 contains the total hours.

For hours 41+, you would then use:

```
=IF(B6 > 40, B6-40, 0)
```

The total wages should now be easy :)

Answer (score 1):

Alternates, for the first 40 hours:

```
=MIN(40,B6)
```

For over 40 hours:

```
=MAX(0,B6-40)
```